# css3 moz-linear-gradient not working

Tags: css, firefox, gradient

For some reason my webkit definition works on chrome but in firefox 3.5.11 I am not seeing my gradient.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
body{
  height:100%;
  background-color: #eaebeb;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eaebeb, #fff);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#eaebeb), to(#fff));
}
```

I have tried examples on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_gradients with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ahem**

At the top of the page:

> Introduced in Gecko 1.9.2 (Firefox 3.6
>   / Thunderbird 3.1 / Fennec 1.0)

Of course it won't work in Firefox 3.5.

Comment: @Yi Thanks mate :-) I assumed I had the newest since I'm running fedora 13 here but apparently not on 3.6 yet so I did not even think to check version.

Answer (score 2):

Change `background-image` to `background` when using gradients.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `background`, not `background-image`.

Comment: using "background-image" is a workaround to allow for older browsers. as it will place the "image" of the gradient above the background colour. If you use a non-solid gradient (i.e. a gradient with an alpha of less then 1) you may get some unexpected effects (the colour will show through the gradient) but in the example shown it should work fine (assuming you have a newer browser).